# how to separate an object joined by animation

Tags: edit-mode

I am trying to pull apart an object which is 'linked' to a 'parent' via animation.
I cannot seem to select the 'dotted black line' joining the object to it's 'parent' and when I select the animation in the node and delete it the object is also removed.
I have also tried 'separation' (press P) which I cannot get to work.
Is there a way and if so how do I do it?
Refer screen image below - red arrow is pointing to the dotted black line (hard to see).[image]
Thanks

Comment: 'P' is to Parent. ALT-P to unparent. The dotted black line is purely a gizmo showing the link, not something you can click on to select!

Comment: Thanks John. Silly me never gave it a thought to look up 'parent' (in the manual) I just thought of the word (parent) to ensure the reader understood what I mean. And I used 'clear and keep transformation' so that the objects didn't 'jump' to another position. Can't remember how to close this as 'solved'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>P</kbd> parents an object. <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>P</kbd> unparents it.

You can remove the dotted relationship lines from the viewport by unchecking the option in the Overlays menu if you wish:

[image]